# What are the Eigenvectors in the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, 3d, matrix-equations

I have the matrix A:

\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 4 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 4\\
\end{bmatrix}

I found $\lambda I_n - A$ to be:

\begin{bmatrix}
(\lambda -4) & -2 & -2\\
-2 & (\lambda -4) & -2\\
-2 & -2 & (\lambda -4)\\
\end{bmatrix}

Applying Sarrus' Rule, and with help in a previous question, I determined the Eigenvalues to be $\lambda = 8$ or $2$ from the polynomial $\lambda^3 -12\lambda^2 +36\lambda -32 = 0$

If I now get the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & -2\\
\end{bmatrix} when verifying $\lambda = 2$, does this mean that $\lambda = 2$ is not a valid Eigenvalue? Or does it mean that $(\lambda I_n -A)v = 0$
Vector v = 1? And creates an Eigenspace from this?

Checking for $\lambda = 8$ gives me:
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -2 & -2\\
-2 & 6 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}

How do I get the Eigenvectors for this?

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial factors as $(\lambda-8)(\lambda-2)^2$.

Comment: Since the rows have constant sum, there is a very obvious eigenvector with eigenvalue $8$ equal to that sum.

Comment: For the case where $\lambda =8$ I believe you should get $4$ instead of $6$ on the diagonal, which gives you $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ as an eigenvector (as pointed out by Mark).

Comment: @Arnaud How does $\lambda = 8$ give you $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ from \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 4 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}

Comment: @Gabi The sum of the elements of each line is $4-2-2=0$, which is equivalent to $$\begin{bmatrix}4 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 4 & -2\\ -2 & -2 & 4\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}=0,$$which can be rewritten as $(8Id-A)\cdot v=0$ (where $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$), which shows that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $8$.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits in my previous comment, the equations should be fine now.

Comment: @Arnaud I see thank you! So, from that I'm getting that $4v_1 = 2v_2 + 2v_3$ and in row two, $4v_2 = 2v_1 + 2v_3$, so $v_1 = \frac{(v_2 + v_3)}{2}$, substitute this to row two and you get that $v_2 = v_3$, so their ratio's in essence are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ Am I correct?

Comment: @Gabi Yes you can see it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to check for eigenvalues is to factorize
$$
x^3 - 12x^2 + 36x -32 = \left(x-8\right)\left(x-2\right)^2
$$
Then to get the eigenvectors, input the eigenvalues one by one to
$$
(\lambda I - A) \cdot \begin{bmatrix}S_1\\S_2\\S_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and solve for $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that your characteristic equation has double roots, so you can find infinitely many (coplanar) eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=2.$

You need to find any two non-zero and non-parallel vectors satisfying the single equation $-2x-2y-2z=0$